# React Native ios: App crashes when it sent to the background

Tags: ios, crash, react-native

I have a React Native ios app. I'm trying to solve a problem but I couldn't manage to solve it yet.

When I send the app to the background with pressing the home button twice or whenever I pass to another app, app crashes. You can see the video below;

[You can see error image with this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk8kT.jpg)

http://sendvid.com/gwoqfybp

Error:

```
2016-11-08 20:51:58.874 NewsApp[33572:686315] -[RCTDeviceExtension orientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001d100
2016-11-08 20:51:58.884 NewsApp[33572:686315] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.15 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: -[RCTDeviceExtension orientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001d100
2016-11-08 20:51:59.018 NewsApp[33572:686315] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
2016-11-08 20:51:59.961503 NewsApp[33572:689959] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 210 Connection has no connected handler
2016-11-08 20:52:03.298381 NewsApp[33572:689437] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 211 Connection has no connected handler
2016-11-08 20:52:04.005 NewsApp[33572:686315] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTDeviceExtension orientationDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000001d100'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010789f34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106ccb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010790ef34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107824c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107824798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010783d19c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010783d09b _CFXRegistrationPost + 427
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010783ce02 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077ffea2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 2018
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077fef3b _CFXNotificationPost + 667
    10  Foundation                          0x00000001067930ab -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000108d24e3e -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 633
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108d2c712 __62-[UIApplication _sceneSettingsPostLifecycleEventDiffInspector]_block_invoke.1251 + 107
    13  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc1a7f5 __52-[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:]_block_invoke.27 + 231
    14  Foundation                          0x00000001067f7199 __NSIndexSetEnumerate + 1027
    15  BaseBoard                           0x000000010be05acb -[BSSettingsDiff inspectChangesWithBlock:] + 116
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc14354 -[FBSSettingsDiff inspectOtherChangesWithBlock:] + 92
    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc1a598 -[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:] + 332
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000108d2d1a8 __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 201
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108d2cdea -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 1060
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000109258676 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 492
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc0302e __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.376 + 204
    22  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc31723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc3159c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bc31925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107844311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010782959c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107828a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107828494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b819a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000108d2f964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    31  NewsApp                             0x0000000102822dcf main + 111
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a70668d start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**Solution**

Basically problem caused by a Google Analytics plugin. I switched to Fribase Analytics and problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the app state and make sure no processes are running like push notifications that won't run in the background. Try to post the code that's running and I will try to change my answer.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    currentAppState: AppState.currentState,
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
_handleAppStateChange: function(currentAppState) {
  this.setState({ currentAppState, });
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <Text>Current state is: {this.state.currentAppState}</Text>
  );
},
```

read more here for full example and documentation
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

Comment: @ilker Also, try it out on a phone and see how it runs in the background. Some things don't work properly in the simulator.

Comment: I'm using REDUX, and REDUX-PERSIST so should i do anything about store/state when AppState changes to 'inactive'  or changes to 'active again' to prevent crash?

Comment: @ilker You have to make sure to stop processes like touch notifications when the app is in the background or it will crash. That's the best advice I can give.

Comment: @Ilker Your welcome, sorry I couldn't be more help. Maybe you could post the code that's happening when the app crashes.